# Sumproduct multiple value filter with 2 tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I want to do is:

1. Filter Mpdata[Date] = `2016`
2. Filter Mpdata[Customer] = `Cust a`
3. You get a list of order nummers
4. Use the list of order nummers to filter Wpsdata[Order]
5. Then `SUM` Wpsdata[Cost]

I have tried this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(EXACT({"214543-1"};Mpdata[Order]));WPsdata[Cost])
```

I get value, but i tried with multiple values that didn't work.

[image]

Note:

1. It may not use a helper column
2. It need to be done with formula only

Comment: 2017 didn't have a 29th February....

Comment: a yes thx.. but it's dummy data in text it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Mpdata` in `C6:E12`, 
`Wpsdata` in `K6:M13`, `Year` in `F3` and `Customer` in `G3`,
using a helper range `H6:H12`.

Enter

```
=SUMIF(H6:H12,"<>#N/A")
```

in `H3`;

enter a formula

```
=INDEX($L$6:$L$13,MATCH(IF((YEAR(C6)=$F$3)*(E6=$G$3)>0,INDEX($D$6:$D$12,(YEAR(C6)=$F$3)*(E6=$G$3)*(ROW(H1)))),$M$6:$M$13,0))
```

in `H6` and drag/copy down to `H12`. The range will be populated
with appropriate cost values from `Wpsdata` table
and the sum will be ready in `H3`.

[image]

Comment: Thx but I can't use a helper column to get this. It only need to be done with the formuler